# Eben darin oder ebendarin?

Tags: spelling

Man schreibt ja "ebendiese" oder "ebenjene" zusammen, wenn damit gemeint ist, "gerade diese" oder "gerade jene" Sache, während man getrennt schreibt, wenn "eben" eher im Sinne von "halt" verwendet wird (das ist halt diese Sache).

Müsste man dann nicht auch "ebendarin" zusammenschreiben, wenn "gerade darin" gemeint ist? Ich finde allerdings auf Google nur sehr wenige Beiträge, die ebendarin zusammenschreiben und auch viele Beiträge, bei denen "eben darin" im Sinne von "gerade darin" verwendet wird.

Beispielssatz: "Wir hatten am Anfang das Problem 1 behandelt, hatten aber die Lösung noch nicht behandelt. Ebendarin/Eben darin wird im Folgenden die Aufgabe bestehen."

Dudensuche ergab aber keinen Treffer für "ebendarin" zusammengeschrieben.

Gibt es dazu eine Vorgabe?

Comment: Wenn du nach Meinungen fragst, muss deine Frage leider geschlossen werden mit dem Grund: »Opinion-based«. Fragen, die Meinungen abfragen, sind im ganzen Stackexchange-Universum ausdrücklich unerwünscht. Dem könntest du entgehen, indem du deine Frage editierst und nicht nach Meinungen, sondern nach den Regeln fragst, die diesen Fall behandeln.

Answer (score 1):

Selbst wenn das Wort "ebendarin" existiert, hat es eine andere Bedeutung als "eben darin". "Ebendarin" ist/wäre äquivalent zu beispielsweise "ebenso", enthält also eine Gleichsetzung hinsichtlich einer örtlichen Angabe ("Die Äpfel sind in der Kiste. Die Bananen sind ebendarin." Das klingt aber sehr komisch und ich bezweifle, dass das Wort "ebendarin" tatsächlich existiert.).

"Eben darin" kann alles mögliche bedeuten, abhängig vom Kontext. "Eben" ist hier eine Art Füllwort bzw. ein Wort zur Betonung von etwas (z. B. "Die Leitung liefert keinen Strom. Eben darin liegt das Problem.").

Comment: Übrigens: Herzlich Willkommen auf german.stackexchange! Cool, dass du gleich mit einer Antwort einsteigst! Das ist eher selten.

Comment: VIelleicht lohnt es sich zu erwähnen, dass diese Analyse auch für _eben dieses_ vs. _ebendieses_ gilt.

_eben_ in "eben darin" bezeichnet man übrigens als [Modalpartikel](https://www.wikiwand.com/de/Modalpartikel) - eine Partikel, die dazu dient, eine Beurteilung des Gesagten von Seiten des Sprechers / der Sprecherin auszudrücken.